# Can I integrate multiple APIs into one standard API using API Management softwares?

Tags: api, wso2, ibm-api-management

I need to use multiple APIs from multiple sources in my new website. They are all similar in functionality but with some differences in format. Then I need to build some type of proxy to make them all the same before use.

*Can I use an API Management solution like WSO2 to integrate all these APIs and standardize them as a single API?*

Is there another solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are actually looking for an integration solution. Therefore, what suits best is the WSO2 Enterprise Integrator. You can write a couple of Synapse code to combine a set of APIs and expose them as one.

Now, if you need to enforce policies such as authentication, authorization, rate-limiting etc. (i.e. if you need to expose this API as a managed API), then only you need APIM in front of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally I installed WSO2 Enterprise Integration Can I user Management Console to do this? There is a "Service Bus > APIs" option in the main menu but nothing about Synapses. How can I add my APIs and manage them?

Comment: Here is a tutorial. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Sending+a+Simple+Message+to+a+Service

Answer (score 1):

[Kloudless](https://kloudless.com) provides an abstraction layer via a single unified API to connect to several third-party APIs without having to implement code for each of them. In that way, it functions as a proxy for all those third-party APIs and abstracts out data models, authentication, error-handling and rate-limiting, and more. (I'm a co-founder)

Answer (score 1):

Use Wso2 Enterprise Integrator where You can create API and Apply the various integration patterns to achieve your requirement. Then if you need you can publish the same in API management.

**ESB requirement:**

You can use either a management console for creating API's or an eclipse designer extension from wso2. For creating API's XML knowledge is enough otherwise it also provides drag and drop feature.You don't require JAVA knowledge as the inbuilt mediators which are shipped with Wso2 ESB is enough. But if you have knowledge of java then you can create custom meditaors(`mediators are used for creating busniess logic`) incase of some special needs. If you don't know JAVA then you can use Javascript, Ruby, Groovy inside script mediator. I prefer for smaller transformation I will use Script mediator if you have larger message size then you can go with class mediator that's where we'll use JAVA. This is all the requirement you need for ESB.

Technologies required for ESB: XML, XPATH, JsonPath, XSLT, Xquery , scripting knowledge(`Javascript, Ruby, Groovy`)etc.

If you are beginner then please refer this tutorial https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Integration+Tutorials

For API management programming knowledge not required.

Comment: What knowledge should I have? Do I need to know JAVA or it can be done with PHP? Do I need to write scripts or Management console is enough?